# How to compare column in two different csv file and replace column from another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a requirement to match column 4 (Grade) from File1 with column 1 (Grade) of File2. If it matches, replace column 4 (Grade) of File1 with column2 (Marks) of File2. If it doesn't match, then leave the value of column 4 (Grade) as is.

File1

```
"RollNo","Name","Age","Grade","Class","Teacher"
"1","Asha","7","A","1","David"
"2","Mona","7","B","1","David"
"3","Sonali","7","C","1","David"
"4","Rani","7","D","1","David"
"5","Raj","7","B","1","David"
```

File2

```
"Grade","Marks"
"A","90"
"B","80"
"C","70"
```

Expected output:

```
"RollNo","Name","Age","Grade","Class","Teacher"
"1","Asha","7","90","1","David"
"2","Mona","7","80","1","David"
"3","Sonali","7","70","1","David"
"4","Rani","7","D","1","David"
"5","Raj","7","80","1","David"
```

Can you please help me with an awk command for this output?
Looking ahead for your response.

Comment: Can any field contain `,`, `"`, or newline (`\n`)? Do your records end with `\n` (common in Unix) or `\r\n`(common in files created on Windows, e.g. a CSV exported from MS-Excel)? Please tag your question with the OS and shell you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the fields in your CSV can't contain `,`s or newlines (`\n`) and you're running a Unix shell:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
    (FNR>1) && ($4 in map) { $4 = map[$4] }
1' file2 file1
"RollNo","Name","Age","Grade","Class","Teacher"
"1","Asha","7","90","1","David"
"2","Mona","7","80","1","David"
"3","Sonali","7","70","1","David"
"4","Rani","7","D","1","David"
"5","Raj","7","80","1","David"
```