# How to exchange matching patterns in a csv file using another two-column csv table

Tags: text-processing, csv-simple

I want find patterns from csv1 (column1) in csv2 (anywhere) and exchange them with patterns from csv1 (column2).

Like following:

-csv1-

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| AA | edc |
| BB | ysc |
| CC | cds |
| DD | erg |

...etc

-csv2-

| column1 | column2 | column3 | ...etc (many more columns) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BB | kj | waa | pds |
| xsd | tkp | etp | AA |
| xrg | AA | DD | CC |
| ggg | rko | blb | DD |
| tpp | apt | CC | www |

The solution is something like in this post... [How to compare column in two different csv file and replace column from another file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633137/how-to-compare-column-in-two-different-csv-file-and-replace-column-from-another?newreg=adaa0ce5effa45bca033c457faebf168)

suggesting:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
    NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
    (FNR>1) && ($4 in map) { $4 = map[$4] }
1' file2 file1
```

This one would work for me. I just need to specify to search through all columns, not just the 4th one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check in all the columns instead of single column, you will need to loop over all the columns and check each of them for the replacement.

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
FNR>1{
       for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i = ($i in map?map[$i]:$i)
}1' csv1 csv2
```

Comment: Works, brilliant, thank you! 
I just added a minor edit for my case:
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }